# Улучшение качества прокрутки в DataGrid с DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf

Есть небольшое приложение на WPF для редактирования таблицы БД. Для редактирования полей, которые являются внешними ключами использую DataGridComboBoxColumn. Проблема в том, что чем больше строк в таблицеи и чем больше значений в ComboBox (при этом столбцов всего 4), тем больше при прокрутке грид подтормаживает. Как можно решить эту проблему?